# Amazon SES + PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to set up amazon SES with PHP. I've scoured the internet and the documentation for AWS PHP SDK but I only see outdated scripts on how to include the actual library and send e-mail. Does anyone here have a working script for using Amazon SES with PHP?

This is the closest I've found to test the script but it doesn't work:

```
require 'src/aws.phar';
use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
try {   
$ses = SesClient::factory(array(
'key'    => 'AKIAJ4ERVU6XXXXXXX',
'secret' => 'kMgagzJmB4Xjw7UD+Md0KNgW+CTE2jCXXXXX/',
'region' => Region::US_EAST_1
));

$ses->verifyEmailIdentity( array(
'EmailAddress' => 'jason@aol.com'
));

}
catch( Exception $e )
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't post your live credentials into the question

Comment: Thanks -- I removed them

Comment: @chronotrigga You should invalidate the keys entirely in the AWS Console.

Answer (score 0):

First, you would want to disable/delete and generate new keypairs so that you would not have to face bad situation as there are scrapers/bots and people who might misuse your access key-pairs.

As for your original question, you didn't describe what didn't work for you. Anyway, since you wanted a working version, check the source code of this: https://github.com/daniel-zahariev/php-aws-ses which will give you enough idea to get yours working.

Comment: Can I ask how he is requiring -- require_once('ses.php'); I see that in the /src/ there is SimpleEmailServices.php. Is this it?

Comment: @chronotrigga it is a curl based implementation that does not use aws's sdk (which essentially wraps accessing of API endpoints) via guzzle. Technically they should be equivalent as long as they behave in the same way. You would want to read this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/installation.html if you wish to use aws-php-sdk. In fact, using aws-php-sdk makes more sense if you're going to use more services than ses. And, yeah you should really be using composer for dep. management.

Comment: i'm only going to be using SES. when you say curl-based, can this be done using php? Ive never really used curl before and not sure where to start.. a pure php option would be best

Comment: @chronotrigga curl-based means, it uses php curl which is widely used so you would not neet to worry about it. There needs to be some way to send http requests and curl is quite good at that. Its a pure php and uses functionalities exposed by php curl library.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code that i got for you, let me know if this helps

```
<?php
require 'aws.phar';
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
$client = SesClient::factory(array('region'=>'us-east-1','version'=> 
   'latest','credentials' => array('key' => 'xxxxx','secret'  => 'xxxxxx',)));
    $msg = array();
    $msg['Source'] = $message['from'];
    $msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = $to_address;
    $msg['ReplyToAddresses'][] = $from;
    $msg['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = $subject;  
    $msg['Message']['Subject']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";
    $msg['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] = $body;
    $msg['Message']['Body']['Html']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";

try{
    $result = $client->sendEmail($msg);
    $logmsg = "Passed ".from." - ".to_address;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $logmsg = "Failed ".$message['from']." - ".$to_address;
    error_log('Failed Email '.from." - ".$to_address); 
}
```